# Is there a password manager that requires no client side installation?

Tags: password-manager

I am trying to find a password manager that I can use in a work environment. The basic requirements are that no client side USB drive or software installation can be required (but a file for the password database can be stored).  This includes browser extensions, but bookmarklets can be used. Cellphones are also not authorized, so a solution that depends on access to a cellphone based authentication is also not tenable.  I have a personally controlled server that can be used to host the server side of a self-hosted solution. Are there any proven solutions that allow for this?

Comment: No installations, but can you run an arbitrary executable (without admin rights)? Or are those blocked?

Comment: No, while it's not locked out, it's not authorized.

Comment: How about USB devices? Can you plug in an arbitrary personal USB device or is that also prohibited?

Comment: No, if it's not employer provided it is unauthorized. The only thing I can think of is something that is purely web-based, with js the only client side element. I do have access to a dedicated server under my control if there is a secure self hosted solution, but would want it to be a easy solution to install securely.

Comment: So, you *can* install and run arbitrary software on a dedicated server, but not on your local PC? Also, can you access cloud storage like dropbox?

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect this, but the server is a personal asset, not a work asset. I am not sure about Dropbox,  but I can use google drive and a NextCloud install.

Comment: It's possible to use LastPass on the website only. Of course it's much easier to use with a browser extension, and setting up 2FA would be good but then most of the time that would depend on a cellphone but not really in the same way as having software on one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be interested in [KeeWeb](https://keeweb.info). KeeWeb can be accessed through a browser using either the [official KeeWeb web app](https://app.keeweb.info/) or you can [self-host your own KeeWeb web app](https://github.com/keeweb/keeweb#self-hosting).

KeeWeb only ever decrypts data on your PC (the author claims everything is done "offline" and client-side), but uses javascript and other web technology instead of native code so you don't *need* to install anything on the device you're using it on (you *can* download a desktop app with a few more features such as auto-type).

KeeWeb uses the same vault format as KeePass so you can be confident the storage is secure. It is fully compatible so you could even use KeePass, KeePass2Android, etc. with the same password database if you choose to do so. Just be aware that the Argon2 implementation is currently *much* slower in KeeWeb than in KeePass itself so I'd recommend using the AES-based key derivation for now.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I'm looking for, especially with the NextCloud app version on [GitHub](https://github.com/jhass/nextcloud-keeweb).